# How can I filter data in this way?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

models.py:

```
class InjuredLocation(models.Model):
    reportperson = models.ForeignKey(ReportPerson)
    mark1 = models.BooleanField('Mark1', default=False)
    mark2 = models.BooleanField('Mark2', default=False)
    mark3 = models.BooleanField('Mark3', default=False)       

class Report(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
   report_number = models.CharField('report Number', max_length=100)

class ReportPerson(models.Model):   
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report)
    action_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=ACTION_TYPE)
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=100)
```

This is my three models, I want to filter the data from `InjuredLocation` models.

1. Reportperson table contain report id and name field of that table could be multiple.Each report can have multiple names.
2. I want to filter the data from `InjuredLocation` table with reference to `reportperson_id`.
3. The filtered data should be for the equivalent report.

tried:

```
 injury_list = []
    reportperson = ReportPerson.objects.filter(report=report_id, action_type="involved")    
    injuary_mark = InjuredLocation.objects.filter(pk=reportperson)
    for injuary in injuary_mark:
        mark = InjuredLocation.objects.get(pk=injuary.id)
        marklist={'mark':mark}        
        injury_list.append(marklist)
```

I am getting this error "(1242, 'Subquery returns more than 1 row')" in 5th line,if Reportperson table have more than one name.

update:

```
injuery_list = []
injuries = InjuredLocation.objects.filter(reportperson__report=report_id, reportperson__action_type="involved")
for reportperson in injuries:    
    injun = InjuredLocation.objects.get(pk=reportperson.id)
    list_inju = {'person': injun}
    injuery_list.append(list_inju)
```

Able to take the objects from InjuredLocation models,in template i rendered it but problem is "it should render against reportperson_id,instead it is rendering all" for example if InjuredLocation models have reportperson_id=1,mark1=0 & mark2=1 and for reportperson_id=2,mark1=1 & mark2=0 it is rendering all like this "1 1" for both reportperson_id.The expected output is 0 1 and 1 0.What ever selected are all comes to display for all reportperson_id.

template is

```
{%for injuary_mark in injuery_list%}
    {%if injuary_mark.person.mark1 %}<img style="float: right; margin:5px 4px -35px 0;" src="{{BASE_URL}}/static/images/red-cross.png"> {% endif %}
    {%if injuary_mark.person.mark2 %}<img style="float: right;margin:5px 8px -35px -8px;" src="{{BASE_URL}}/static/images/red-cross.png"> {% endif %}
{%endfor%}
```

**Last update:**

I want to show the details in InjuredLocation models against id in the Reportperson models.This is from a single report,see the Report models in the figure.

All the three models with data i pasted below.

[image: Reportperson model]
[image: InjuredLocation model]
[image: Report model]

What i required as output is,a tab will be dynamically created when a row in InjuredLocation model is created against id in Reportperson table.I want to show the mark from InjuredLocation table against their respective id from Reportperson table in their respective tabs.Now all the mark whatever created against id in Reportperson model are shown in all tabs.Assume mark for id=1 is empty and Marks for id=2 and id=3 are their in database,as per requirement tab1 should not show any data,but now tab1 is showing data of tab2 and tab3 from id=2 and id=3's data.Need help

Comment: The error is saying that `.get()` requires to return 1 object, but here, it returns multiple objects.

Comment: first i think you would have to address the issue with `get` you have.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with this line:

```
injuary_mark = InjuredLocation.objects.filter(pk=reportperson)
```

The exception refers to a different line because that's where the queryset is actually evaluated.

There are two problems here.

The fatal one is that `reportperson` is not a single value - it's a queryset:

```
reportperson = ReportPerson.objects.filter(report=report_id, action_type="involved")
```

As you note, 'each report can have multiple names' - and this will find all of them that match the action_type, so it's not an appropriate value to use in an exact lookup.

Also, you almost certainly do not mean `pk=reportperson` - even if `reportperson` were a single value, you're filtering on the wrong field.

The fix is somewhat dependent on what exactly you want to do with the multiple names.  If you just want to get all the `InjuredLocation` instances that relate to the report_id regardless of report name, this is a more concise expression:

```
injuries = InjuredLocation.objects.filter(reportperson__report_id=report_id, reportperson__action_type="involved")
```

If necessary you could use your original `reportperson` lookup and then an `__in` filter, but the version above using `__` to filter on related values is more concise.  In the database, `__in` uses a subquery while filtering using `__` performs a join; the two can have different performance.  The `__in` version would be:

```
 reportpeople = ReportPerson.objects.filter(report=report_id, action_type="involved")
 injuries = InjuredLocation.objects.filter(reportperson__in=reportpeople)
```

If you want to keep each `InjuredLocation` instance with its `ReportPerson` instance, say because you're going to group them in a template:

```
reportpeople = ReportPerson.objects.filter(report_id=report_id, action_type="involved")
for reportperson in reportpeople:
    injuries = reportperson.injuredlocation_set.all()
    # now do something with them
```

Edited:

> if you given me a sample how to make the queryset and how to iterate in template will be a great help for me

Something like:

In the view:

```
reportpeople = ReportPerson.objects.filter(report_id=report_id, action_type="involved")
return render('mytemplate.html', {'reportpeople': reportpeople})
```

In the template:

```
{% for reportperson in reportpeople %}
  <p>Report name: {{ reportperson.name }}</p>
  <ul>
    {% for injured_location in reportperson.injuredlocation_set.all %}
      <li>
        {% if injured_location.mark1 %}
          <img style="float: right; margin:5px 4px -35px 0;" src="{{BASE_URL}}/static/images/red-cross.png"> {% endif %}
        {% if injured_location.mark2 %}
          <img style="float: right;margin:5px 8px -35px -8px;" src="{{BASE_URL}}/static/images/red-cross.png"> {% endif %}
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Or whatever HTML you want for each report name.  The point is that you can get at the `InjuredLocation` instances related to a particular `ReportPerson` instance via the `injuredlocation_set` manager.

Comment: Peter DeGlopper,Thanks for the detailed explanation.Can you please check my update in question,which i had tried.It is rendering all the values for all reportperson_id,should render the value against their respective  reportperson_id

Comment: Both your explanation and your example code are hard to follow - a lot of what your updated code does is unnecessary, and the variable names don't correspond to your class names at all.  That said, I think what you're trying to do is best accomplished by retrieving your `ReportPerson` instances, passing that queryset to the template, and then iterating over `injuryreport_set.all` in your template.  Given a `ReportPerson` instance, `injuryreport_set` is a manager that will return the `InjuryReport` instances related to that `ReportPerson`.

Comment: You have yet to state your requirement in a manner I can understand.  I have reached the point where I am no longer willing to put time into this question, but if you can more clearly describe both your expected output (in HTML, not general descriptions of tabs) and what output your templates are currently producing it might help anyone else who feels like trying to help you.